# How to trigger the select event handler in jqueryui autocomplete combobox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, combobox, jquery-autocomplete, eventtrigger

I have a jqueryui autocomplete combo-box widget in which once the user selects something in the combobox, the select event handler within the combo-box makes an ajax call to render content in another div element. EG:

[combo-box] > [div]

The div contains content in which the user can then click submit to go to a different page.

I am running into a problem in which if the user clicks on the back button AFTER having made a selection within the combo-box and then clicking within the div to go to the next page, the combo-box will display the last selected value, but the div will display the value as it was originally rendered on the page, prior to the ajax request (which populated the div with dynamic content). As a result, the displayed value within the combo-box is now inconsistent with the displayed content in the div.

The solution to this problem requires that I trigger the select of a certain value within the combo-box when the page is first loaded, so that the select event handler within the jqueryui autocomplete combobox code is run, which will reload the div.

What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the selected value into a hidden input and on page load paint the content div with the value in the hidden input (if any)

Comment: Careful dude, you're at the perfect amount of points as it is.

Comment: @Walkerneo: Sorry, I didn't get your comment

Comment: You have exactly 1337 points. It would be a shame to make or lose any at this point. edit: yes.

Comment: Unfortunately, while I could use javascript to write content into a hidden input, the contents are cleared after I click on a link on the page and then click on the back button. The only exception is if I make the input to be type=text instead of type=hidden, but this only works in chrome and not in firefox. However, the text within the combobox input seems to be persisted even when the back button is pressed in both chrome and firefox. How does jqueryui do it?

Comment: I meant the selected value of combobox to be stored in the hidden input and to do an ajax call on `document.ready` if the hidden input has any value. But it's strange the hidden input is not persisted when the user hits the back button! Would you want to post any code at all?

Comment: Ok. I got it to work now. As it turns out, firefox requires that the input is surrounded by &lt;form&gt; tags in order for it to be 'remembered'. Also, in chrome, hidden inputs will not be remembered whereas non-hidden inputs (even with style="display:none;") will be remembered.

Comment: Glad you could resolve it... and good learnings those about the Firefox and Chrome nuances